# Can I use an overloaded prefix ++ operator for the postfix ++ operator in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

In C++ (particularly, Visual Studio 2013 C++), I met a confusing code as:

```
class C {
   C operator++() {
      ...
   }
   // C operator++(int dummy) {
   // ...
   // }
}

C obj;

++obj;  // This should be fine!
obj++;  // This should not be fine, but there is no compilation error.
```

In obj++, the overloaded prefix++ is called in the example.
I thought the program should not be compiled.

Any idea on this?

Comment: `warning C4620: no postfix form of 'operator ++' found for type 'C', using prefix form` - and yes, that code is ill-formed, but the compiler's obligation is limited to issuing a diagnostic message, which it did with the warning.

Comment: doesn't compile on g++ http://ideone.com/ZPJuvl, probably you use a compiler extension

Comment: By convention, `operator++()` should return `C&`.

Comment: Great! Thank you T.C. and vsoftco!!!

Comment: Maybe there is out-of-line `C operator++(C, int dummy) { return ++C; }` elsewhere that you are overlooking